# nodejs calling to function from inside an object in module

Tags: node.js, function, object

I have the following module:

```
var util = require('util');
var events = require('events');
exports.IncomingMessage=IncomingMessage;

var IncomingMessage = function (){
    events.EventEmitter.call(this);
    this.headers={};
    this.httpVersion='';
    this.method='';
    this.socket='';
    this.ready=function(){
        console.log('should emit ready');
        //this.emit('ready');
    }

}
```

In my code, I'm doing:

```
var req=require('./newIncomingMessage');
```

and then when I'm calling:

```
req.ready();
```

I'm getting an Error:

```
TypeError : Object #<Object> has no method 'ready'
```

Why is that? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `module.exports = ...` to say what should come out when you require it. If you want it to export an object that has a `.ready` function, you still need

```
....
module.exports = { ready: function() { ... } };
```

that said, I don't see any code in your module that looks like a ready function, so a better question is "what are you trying to do with this code".

On a relatively important note: `req` is a var name generally reserved for http request objects (either in plain nodejs or connect/express) so you're going to confuse a lot of other Node devs by using that as your variable name.

Comment: but .method and all the others are working...
So why the function isn't?

Answer (score 0):

Just didn't recognize IncomingMessage is used before definition.

```
var util = require('util');
var events = require('events');
exports.IncomingMessage = new function(){
  events.EventEmitter.call(this);
  this.headers={};
  this.httpVersion='';
  this.method='';
  this.socket='';
  this.ready=function(){
    console.log('should emit ready');
    //this.emit('ready');
  };
};
```

And before using it

```
var iMsg=require('./newIncomingMessage').IncomingMessage;
```

And then you can use it:

```
iMsg.ready();
```

A brief explanation about it is:

> You can treat new `function(){}` as `{}`, but more than `{}`, because you can do more things in this enclosing scope.
>
> In this example, simply typo
>
> > `typeof iMsg`
>
> your will get an
>
> > `'object'`.

Comment: so should I change the export or shouldn't I? you're suggestion only giving me the same error...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I couldn't understand from the answers above why the approach didn't work. But that's what I used finally:

```
module.exports = IncomingMessage;

function IncomingMessage() {
    this.headers={};
        this.httpVersion='';
        this.method='';
        this.socket='';
    }
IncomingMessage.prototype.ready=function(){
    console.log('Inside ready function');
}
```

Comment: This way is recommended in javascript; putting a function in the constructor has performance and memory issues.  Using prototype is the better solution.  You could also create modules using the module pattern, it works very well with node & modules.